# Definition data of ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl is null

Tags: c++, clang, libclang, libtooling

I recieve a `class alt::VectorLayout<int, 4>` for example, as a ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl and I'm trying to process the field and methods of the class, but it fails on an assertion where the definition data is null. I have the presumption that the template specialization is a forward declaration so it's not instantiated, but I couldn't figure out how to instantiate, even when all the template parameters are provided.

Is it possible to recieve the ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl with a non-null definition data or somehow instantiate it to fill in the definition data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue with `Sema::RequireCompleteType`.
I found that there would be no way to retrieve the `Sema` purely from a `ClangTool` instance. Instead of processing the source files with `ClangTool`, I made a `CompilerInstance` where the instance of the `Sema` was retrievable and ran a `FrontendAction` on the `CompilerInstance`.

CompilerInstance impl: https://github.com/7Hazard/altv-capi/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L111
Sema::RequireCompleteType usage: https://github.com/7Hazard/altv-capi/blob/master/src/templateClass.cpp#L46